# How to solve this partial differential equation? (nonhomogeneous and transient in cylinder co0rrdinate)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The problem is

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+f(r,t)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) \, \, \, \, \ \ \  t>0,\ 0<r<1$

with the boundary condition

$ u=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$  at  $r=1$,

and the initial condition

$u(r,0)=0$

where $u$ is a function of $r$ and $t$, $f(r,t)$ is some known function; $u$ is bounded at $r=0$.

So how to solve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations

Comment: Note: If you tell us what you tried, what you know and where you got stuck (so if you are more specific in your question), we can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. Yes, I was trying to use separation of variables on this. I've got the solution for the homogeneous problem, and it's $\sum T_n(t)J_0(\lambda_nx)$ but I was stuck in the next step. For rectangular coordinate, we can just expand $f(r, t)$ by Fourier expansion. I don't know how do do it for the cylinder coordinate. Is there any method to expand $f(r, t)$ into Bessel function series?